# Log likelihood function, GARCH(1,1) with asymmetric term

Tags: statistics, garch, statistical-finance, log-returns

I am modelling a GARCH(1,1) and a GARCH(1,1) with an asymmetric term.

$$h(t)=\omega+\alpha\varepsilon(t-1)^2+\beta\sigma(t-1)^2$$

and

$$h(t)=\omega+\alpha u(t-1)^2+\beta\sigma(t-1)^2 + \gamma (u(t-1)^2D)$$

$D$ takes a value of 1 if u is positive.

Will my log likelihood function change between these two models?

If so, how will it change?

Thanks!

Comment: The Gaussian quasi log-likelihood function for the the GJR-GARCH(1,1) will be similar, but somewhat different because the variance parameter $h(t)$ is different, provided you have some assumptions on the terms $u$ and $\gamma$.

Comment: Great, how different, could you provide an example of a text where it will show me the difference.

Comment: Try having a look at these books: [book1](https://www.amazon.com/Financial-Modeling-Non-Gaussian-Distributions-Springer/dp/1846284198/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1548418891&sr=8-1&keywords=Financial+Modeling+Under+Non-Gaussian+Distributions) or [book2](https://www.amazon.com/GARCH-Models-Structure-Statistical-Applications-ebook/dp/B07M5MHY3N/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1548419127&sr=8-2&keywords=francq+zakoian+garch)

Comment: are you an expert with these books, could you direct me to specific pages?

Comment: I used them a long time ago. There are sections on the GJR-GARCH model, and you should have the log-likelihood derivation there